# How to combine two filters from two models?

Tags: django, django-views

How to combine two filters from two models?

Must be work as `AND` (&)

```
Credit.objects.filter(id__in=CreditPayment.objects.filter(security='Deposit - deposit').values('credit__id').distinct(), bank__id=1))

Credit.objects.filter(id__in=Condition.objects.filter(purpose=3).values('credit__id').distinct(), bank__id=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [django Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#and) with &

```
from django.db.models import Q
Credit.objects.filter(Q(id__in=CreditPayment.objects.filter(security='Deposit - deposit').values('credit__id').distinct()) & Q(id__in=Condition.objects.filter(purpose=3).values('credit__id').distinct()), bank__id=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given I understood it correctly, you can do this with two filter statements where you join on the `Condition` model, like:

```
Credit.objects.filter(
    bank__id=1,
    condition__security='Deposit - deposit'
).filter(
    condition__purpose=3
).distinct()
```

This yields a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT credit.*
FROM credit
INNER JOIN condition ON credit.id = condition.credit_id
INNER JOIN condition T3 ON credit.id = T3.credit_id
WHERE credit.bank_id = 1
  AND condition.security = Deposit - deposit
  AND T3.purpose = 3
```